# Conditional render of props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have this 2 states, from 2 different api calls
one is 'movieList' and the other one is 'search', Both are array of movies.
movieList is automatically rendered since it is the search for popular movies and it corresponds that the user is shown as soon as he opens the page, in the navbar I have an input attached to a state called search and it saves an array of movies that match the name in it ... try to use a conditional with the following logic, if search exists,  maps search, otherwise map movieList.
but it seems I don't know how to do it correctly. If someone can give me a hand in how to do it, it would help me a lot, thank you very much! here I leave the code

````
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getAllMovies } from '../../features/movieSlice'
import MovieCard from '../MovieCard/MovieCard';

const MovieListing = ({ movieList, search }) => {


   return (
       
        <div className='' >
            <div className=''>
                <div className='my-20 mx-15 flex flex-wrap justify-around items-center' >
           {
           movieList.map((movie)=>(
              <MovieCard {...movie} key={movie.id}  />
           ))} 
       </div>   
       </div> 
       </div>
   )
}

export default MovieListing```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a conditional render you can try use a ternary operator:

```
 <div className='' >
    <div className=''>
        <div className='my-20 mx-15 flex flex-wrap justify-around items-center' >
    {
    search ? search.map((searchItem) => <MapsSearch {...search}/> : 
    movieList.map((movie) => (<MovieCard {...movie} key={movie.id}/>))
    }
       </div>   
    </div> 
</div>
```

(You'll just need to modify the mapping of search and what it returns as I'm not sure what type `search` is)

Comment: Done bro! really appreciated it